# How to delete duplicate data in mySql on new version?

Tags: mysql

[How to delete duplicate data in mySql on new version?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLgVE.png)

```
SchoolId    StudentName 
101        Majid Bhuiyan
101        Majid Bhuiyan
102        Arif
103        Tamim Rahman
104        Sourov Doggesh
```

I expect it mySql code. How to delete only one row in that duplicate row.

SchoolId: 101 StudentName: Majid Bhuiyan
this is two time present in the data table.
Please, Someone help me to remove this problem.

Comment: There is no any data in the table which allows to identify each line. So your task is not solvable now in the single query form. Add some primary key (for example, autoincremented one) then delete.

Comment: The question implies there are never 2 students with the same name per schoolid , this seems an unsafe assumption in the real world, however if this is just a homework question?

Comment: Also what do you mean by 'on new version'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can delete the duplicate rows by using **join** but I will suggest you to go with a simple method that is to create a new table using the below code

```sql
CREATE TABLE copy_of_table 
SELECT DISTINCT SchoolId,StudentName
FROM table_name;
```

It will create a new table and will take only the unique value of SchoolId from your table and hence the duplicate rows will not be there in the new table

Upvote if you like the answer

While creating a table you must set a column as UNIQUE or PRIMARY key(Most of the time it is the Id column) to avoid such things

The syntax for this is

```sql
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    UNIQUE (ID)
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The below procedure removes all completely duplicated rows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE remove_duplicates ()
BEGIN
-- START TRANSACION;
REPEAT
    DELETE
    FROM test t1
    WHERE (SchoolId, StudentName) IN (
        SELECT * 
        FROM (
            SELECT SchoolId, StudentName
            FROM test t2
            GROUP BY 1, 2
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            ) t2
        )
    LIMIT 1;
UNTIL NOT ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT;
-- COMMIT;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LZNBEqdw)

Of course, it is slow because it deletes the rows one-by-one. Uncommenting the transactional statement must increase the deletion speed but this may result in the interference with concurrent processes.

---

**UPDATE**

Another procedure version which deletes all single duplicates in one step. This must be more fast, especially here is many duplicates for each separate values pair. But it maybe more slow when the duplicates are rare.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE remove_duplicates ()
BEGIN
-- START TRANSACION;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE vSchoolId VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE vStudentName VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE vCnt INT;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT SchoolId, StudentName, COUNT(*) - 1 cnt
  FROM test
  GROUP BY 1, 2
  HAVING cnt;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
PREPARE stmt FROM 'DELETE FROM test WHERE SchoolId = ? AND StudentName = ? LIMIT ?';
OPEN cur;
read_loop: LOOP
  FETCH cur INTO vSchoolId, vStudentName, vCnt;
  SET @vSchoolId=vSchoolId, @vStudentName=vStudentName, @vCnt=vCnt;
  IF done THEN 
    LEAVE read_loop;
  END IF;
  EXECUTE stmt USING @vSchoolId, @vStudentName, @vCnt;
END LOOP;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
CLOSE cur;
-- COMMIT;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iIHsmxXS)

Comment: Have to agree, this is a really good answer

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought as the last resort after spending serveral futile hours trying to solve it using a single dml statement. Regarding `delete limit 1` in a loop , I even thought of throwing in a sleep function to set a interval once a while or put a low_priority modifier for the delete statement. But is that really necessary for delete limit 1 loop?

Comment: @blabla_bingo See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find similar rows by `group by` and aggregate id by min or max depending on what record you want to delete.

```
DELETE FROM DETAILS
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(id)
    FROM DETAILS
    GROUP BY EMPNAME, DEPT, CONTACTNO, CITY
);
Select * FROM DETAILS;
```

As you can see here am deleting the duplicate record with min id (meaning the one created first, if the ids are auto-generated).

Hope this helps !

Comment: There is **NO** `id` column in the table. So OP must add it previously (and maybe drop it after).

Comment: If it is an absolute duplicate you can go with a temp table approach, where, you can simply fetch everything from the parent table using group-by and then insert to the temp table, then truncate the original table and bring the data back

Comment: You are operating in vain with guesses, not facts. Your recommendations may be non-applicable in some particular cases. OP must expand his question with additional info.

Comment: I agree with Akina. We are not certain if an `id` column can be readily added in the table. And if it is a production environment, a ddl could cause a temporary service downtime.

Comment: @Akina I saw your answer regarding `How to delete duplicate records in MySQL, in a table without IDs` in stackexchange. I was wondering if it's possible to achieve the goal without resorting to DDL ?

Comment: @blabla_bingo Yes, it is possible (but slow) - see provided answer.

Comment: The answer below by @Akina solves the id problem, please check